# dhcp-relay cannot recieve DHCPOFFER packet from DHCP server in shared network

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, tcpdump, dnsmasq

I'm using the `dnsmasq` service as a DHCP server. I have a bridged interface per node named `br0` that has two ip addresses assigned to it. One is the public IP address and the other one is considered the internal network.

I have two nodes and their public IP addresses are in separate subnets. However, their private ip addresses are in the same network. `server` is considered as the node that the `dnsmasq` is serving on it, and `relay` is considered as the node that a VM is running on it. The VM has a TAP device that has been attached to the bridge `br0`.

The internal network is in the `192.168.10.0/24` subnet, `server` node private ip is `192.168.10.1`, and `relay` node private ip is `192.168.10.2`.

I must say that the defined ip pool in the `dnsmasq` service that should be assigned to VMs is in a different subnet rather than other existing subnets.

Here is the configurations of the `dnsmasq` service on the `server` node:

```
interface=br0
listen-address=127.0.0.1,192.168.10.2
shared-network=192.168.10.1,X.Y.Z.12
dhcp-range=X.Y.Z.12,X.Y.Z.127,255.255.255.0,1d
dhcp-option=option:router,X.Y.Z.1
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,8.8.8.8,1.1.1.1
dhcp-broadcast
```

I have tested several dhcp-relay services on the `relay` node such as `isc-dhcp-relay`, `dhcp-helper`, and `dnsmasq` itself which provides the `dhcp-relay` option. But the VM on the `relay` node can't get any IP address from the DHCP server placed on the `server` node.

Below is the configuration file of the `dnsmasq` placed on the `relay` node as dhcp-relay service.

```
dhcp-relay=192.168.10.1,192.168.10.2
```

Here are logs showed by dhcp-server:

```bash
Aug 15 12:32:50 server dnsmasq-dhcp[595455]: DHCPDISCOVER(br0) 52:54:a0:02:02:a1
Aug 15 12:32:50 server dnsmasq-dhcp[595455]: DHCPOFFER(br0) X.Y.Z.23 52:54:a0:02:02:a1
Aug 15 12:32:50 server dnsmasq-dhcp[595455]: DHCPDISCOVER(br0) 52:54:a0:02:02:a1
Aug 15 12:32:50 server dnsmasq-dhcp[595455]: DHCPOFFER(br0) X.Y.Z.23 52:54:a0:02:02:a1
Aug 15 12:32:55 server dnsmasq-dhcp[595455]: DHCPDISCOVER(br0) 52:54:a0:02:02:a1
Aug 15 12:32:55 server dnsmasq-dhcp[595455]: DHCPOFFER(br0) X.Y.Z.23 52:54:a0:02:02:a1
```

Below is the output of `tcpdump` captured on ports 67 and 68 of the bridge `br0` interface on the  `server` node:

```bash
12:32:55.461965 52:54:a0:02:02:a1 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 52:54:a0:02:02:a1, length 300, xid 0x956c917e, secs 7, Flags [none] (0x0000)
          Client-Ethernet-Address 52:54:a0:02:02:a1
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Discover
            Hostname (12), length 10: "test-relay"
            Parameter-Request (55), length 13: 
              Subnet-Mask (1), BR (28), Time-Zone (2), Default-Gateway (3)
              Domain-Name (15), Domain-Name-Server (6), Unknown (119), Hostname (12)
              Netbios-Name-Server (44), Netbios-Scope (47), MTU (26), Classless-Static-Route (121)
              NTP (42)
            END (255), length 0
            PAD (0), length 0, occurs 29
12:32:55.462108 2e:b0:bf:e2:73:9e > 2e:18:10:8c:25:4f, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 39650, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    192.168.10.1.67 > 192.168.10.2.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 52:54:a0:02:02:a1, length 300, hops 1, xid 0x956c917e, secs 7, Flags [none] (0x0000)
          Gateway-IP 192.168.10.1
          Client-Ethernet-Address 52:54:a0:02:02:a1
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Discover
            Hostname (12), length 10: "test-relay"
            Parameter-Request (55), length 13: 
              Subnet-Mask (1), BR (28), Time-Zone (2), Default-Gateway (3)
              Domain-Name (15), Domain-Name-Server (6), Unknown (119), Hostname (12)
              Netbios-Name-Server (44), Netbios-Scope (47), MTU (26), Classless-Static-Route (121)
              NTP (42)
            END (255), length 0
            PAD (0), length 0, occurs 29
12:32:55.462318 2e:18:10:8c:25:4f > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 58284, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    SERVER.PUBLIC.IP.ADDRESS.67 > 255.255.255.255.68: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, xid 0x956c917e, secs 7, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
          Your-IP X.Y.Z.23
          Server-IP 192.168.10.2
          Client-Ethernet-Address 52:54:a0:02:02:a1
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Offer
            Server-ID (54), length 4: 192.168.30.2
            Lease-Time (51), length 4: 86400
            RN (58), length 4: 43200
            RB (59), length 4: 75600
            Subnet-Mask (1), length 4: 255.255.255.0
            BR (28), length 4: X.Y.Z.255
            Domain-Name-Server (6), length 8: 8.8.8.8,1.1.1.1
            Default-Gateway (3), length 4: X.Y.Z.1
            END (255), length 0
            PAD (0), length 0, occurs 4
12:32:55.462557 2e:18:10:8c:25:4f > 2e:b0:bf:e2:73:9e, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 37343, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    192.168.10.2.67 > 192.168.10.1.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, hops 1, xid 0x956c917e, secs 7, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
          Your-IP X.Y.Z.23
          Server-IP 192.168.10.2
          Gateway-IP 192.168.10.1
          Client-Ethernet-Address 52:54:a0:02:02:a1
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Offer
            Server-ID (54), length 4: 192.168.10.2
            Lease-Time (51), length 4: 86400
            RN (58), length 4: 43200
            RB (59), length 4: 75600
            Subnet-Mask (1), length 4: 255.255.255.0
            BR (28), length 4: 195.206.171.255
            Domain-Name-Server (6), length 8: 8.8.8.8,1.1.1.1
            Default-Gateway (3), length 4: X.Y.Z.1
            END (255), length 0
            PAD (0), length 0, occurs 4
12 packets captured
12 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

And Below is the output of `tcpdump` captured on ports 67 and 68 of the bridge `br0` interface on the `relay` node:

```bash
tcpdump: listening on br0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
12:32:47.818621 52:54:a0:02:02:a1 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, fl)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 52:54:a0:02:02:a1, length 300, xid 0x956c917e, Flags [n)
          Client-Ethernet-Address 52:54:a0:02:02:a1
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Discover
            Hostname (12), length 10: "test-relay"
            Parameter-Request (55), length 13: 
              Subnet-Mask (1), BR (28), Time-Zone (2), Default-Gateway (3)
              Domain-Name (15), Domain-Name-Server (6), Unknown (119), Hostname (12)
              Netbios-Name-Server (44), Netbios-Scope (47), MTU (26), Classless-Static-Route (121)
              NTP (42)
            END (255), length 0
            PAD (0), length 0, occurs 29
12:32:47.818830 2e:b0:bf:e2:73:9e > 2e:18:10:8c:25:4f, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 37786, offset 0,)
    192.168.10.1.67 > 192.168.10.2.67: [bad udp cksum 0xbe99 -> 0x2f1c!] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 52:54:a0:02:02:a1, length 300, h)
          Gateway-IP 192.168.10.1
          Client-Ethernet-Address 52:54:a0:02:02:a1
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Discover
            Hostname (12), length 10: "test-relay"
            Parameter-Request (55), length 13: 
              Subnet-Mask (1), BR (28), Time-Zone (2), Default-Gateway (3)
              Domain-Name (15), Domain-Name-Server (6), Unknown (119), Hostname (12)
              Netbios-Name-Server (44), Netbios-Scope (47), MTU (26), Classless-Static-Route (121)
              NTP (42)
            END (255), length 0
            PAD (0), length 0, occurs 29
6 packets captured
6 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

From the `tcpdump` output I understand the below points:

1- `server` node can receive DHCP discover packets from the `relay` node and can send back DHCP offer to the `relay` service. But the `relay` node can't receive the DHCP offer packet from the `server`.

2- Whenever the `relay` service sends DHCP discovery packets to `server`, its packets have a `bad udp checksum`. However, the same packet received by the `server` has the checksum equal to OK.

### My question:

**Why the relay service cannot receive the DHCP offer packet and how to fix it?**

Any help is appreciated.